# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC - Error working with Excel and C#

Tags: c#

I use .net 3.5 with c# as code behind.. i create a excel file .. and write into it cell by cell .. as the data is very less .. every thing works fine in my local which runs on windows xp and excel 2003 .. but wen the same code is deployed in a machine which runs windows 2008 server with exel 2003 it throws an error - Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC .. Kindly help !

Comment: Type "0x800A03EC" in the search box at the upper right corner of this page, you'll find 97 questions about it.  Explain how none of the answers helped you.

Answer (score 0):

If the 2008 server is 64-bit and your work machine is 32-bit you may need to compile for 64 bit and/or run as 32 bit on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to create the directory "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop". It seems like that directory is needed on server machines when scripting things like excel.

See this article for instance: http://bit.ly/MrGwjg